# Where to build the OLAP cubes?

Tags: data-warehouse, olap

I have built a data warehouse with multiple fact tables and dimension tables (with a MySQL server).

Now where could I build the OLAP cubes and write the MDX queries to produce results?

BTW, I have some understanding of the cube building on Apache Kylin, but I think that limited to our business type and amount of data, using Kylin is not a good solution currently now.

I know that Kylin is based on Hadoop. Maybe what we need is an OLAP server based on a RDBMS?

**EDIT:** 
 The reason I'm asking this is because I'm the only data analyst of our team. I used to produce reports with Power BI Desktop, and load the data from our business system MySQL database directly. This worked very well.

We have 400,000 users, the largest table in our databases is about 2 million rows.

Our director think we should use OLAP cubes to speed up the report producing. After designing the fact-dimension data warehouse, I don't know what's the next step ?

Comment: Welcome to DBA SE. It sounds like your question is asking for product reccomendations, without more detail and/or a specfic replies will be largely opinion based. Can you please edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: Did you gather any requirements or do any analysis before you started developing? It's a bit unusual to be asking which OLAP cube you should get or if you even need one at this point in your project. Why do you think you need OLAP?

Comment: @SirSwears-a-lot, question edited.

Comment: Ok so youre looking at OLAP because you have a reporting performance problem. Before you commit to buying a product have to tried improving query performance?

Comment: Are you limited to free products? Or do you have a budget to buy something?

Comment: @SirSwears-a-lot We are not limit to free products. By performance problem, I don't mean the SQL query is running slow. It's that now all our reports are designed in a *static* way, say we have many pages of charts and tables in an internal portal. But we can not drill up / down on any charts. So every time we want to produce a new report we need to create a new page in the portal. Our director want to use OLAP to make the reports more flexible, with filters and drill. It's like involved with BI.